# For Loop generate sequence

Tags: python

Need help,

I expected the output like this

```
1.1.1.1 is server0
1.1.1.2 is server1
1.1.1.3 is server2
1.1.1.4 is server3
```

But I don't get the output like I expected. Here's my code

```
IP = ['1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.2', '1.1.1.3', '1.1.1.4']
for ip in IP:
    for i in range(len(IP)):
        print(ip + ' is ' + 'server'+ str(i))
```

Output:

```
1.1.1.1 is server0
1.1.1.1 is server1
1.1.1.1 is server2
1.1.1.1 is server3
1.1.1.2 is server0
1.1.1.2 is server1
1.1.1.2 is server2
1.1.1.2 is server3
1.1.1.3 is server0
1.1.1.3 is server1
1.1.1.3 is server2
1.1.1.3 is server3
1.1.1.4 is server0
1.1.1.4 is server1
1.1.1.4 is server2
1.1.1.4 is server3
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Use enumerate : `for i, ip in enumerate(IP):
    print(ip + ' is ' + 'server'+ str(i))`

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit. Don't fundamentally alter your question after it already received an answer. If you have a new question, then post a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two loops here. Simply write:

```
for i in range(len(IP)):
            print(IP[i] + ' is ' + 'server'+ str(i))
```

Output:

```
1.1.1.1 is server0
1.1.1.2 is server1
1.1.1.3 is server2
1.1.1.4 is server3
```

Comment: `for i, ip in enumerate(IP): print(ip + ' is server' + str(i))` Is a nice way to do it.

Comment: Yeah, but i think time complexity of both of them are almost same.

Comment: Time complexity shouldn't be an issue for a simple loop. When you want to use the index and the item during iteration, `enumerate()` is the most pythonic choice.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your point